# Unable to play sound twice Android MediaPlayer application crashing

Tags: android, audio

Unable to play sound twice causing Android `MediaPlayer` application to crash

```
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.audio1);
    final ImageButton play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_button_dua_seher);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                    mp.release();
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.audio1);
                }
                mp.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    final ImageButton stop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop_button_dua_seher);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mp != null)
            {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
            }
        }
    });
```

**Logcat**

```
06-15 14:34:59.470 11697-11697/com.toptech.android.ramadanduas

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.toptech.android.ramadanduas, PID: 11697
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaPlayer.isPlaying(Native Method)
at com.toptech.android.ramadanduas.duaseher$2.onClick(duaseher.java:53)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit
```

Comment: mb player isPlaying and u play again?=)

Comment: First Time played correct second tap on stop button cause crashing in app. See Java file also Thank you in advance

Comment: Stop Button Working Properly Now (y) but Play button cannot play sound on second attempt after stop first time...!! Suggestion needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is you call `release()` on your `MediaPlayer` instance when clicking the stop button, but you don't check it's state when (re)starting the playback.

This means you could call `isPlaying()` on a released `MediaPlayer` instance, which will lead to an `IllegalStateException`.

You should somehow keep track of the state of the `MediaPlayer` instance (with a `boolean` flag for example) or set it to `null` after the release so you could perform `null` value checks after.

You could do something like this:

```
// in your play button's onClick()
if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) { // check for null value also
    mp.stop();
    mp.reset();
} else {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.audio1);
}
mp.start();
```

and

```
// in your stop button's onClick()
mp.release();
mp = null; // set it to null
```